# WP-cerber blocks IP : "We’re sorry, you are not allowed to proceed. Our server stopped processing your request..."

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm using 'Redirection' plugin to redirect old website URLs to new website.
There are some URLs with .aspx pages and these URLs are blocked by WP-cerber plugin.

Error shown on browser:
"**We’re sorry, you are not allowed to proceed
Our server stopped processing your request. Your request looks suspicious or similar to automated requests from spam posting software.
If you believe you should be able to perform this request, please let us know.**"

In wp-cerber dashboard that list events, my IP show with this message: Probing for vulnerable PHP code – Locked out

I’m using custom login field “sky”.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any luck with the issue of wp-cerber plugin, but here is my solution with HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Redirect 301 /xxx/xxx.aspx https://newsite.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because: 1) there are no such pages on your website and 2) the requested pages have an extension that allows executing them on the server. So the plugin suspects that some bot or hacker tries to find vulnerable/insecure code to exploit it. Anyway, you can ignore that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gregory. Is there any way in WP Cerber plugin that we can allow/white-list such URLs? Otherwise it will be very difficult for non-technical users of WordPress to do such redirections with HTACCESS file.

Comment: Go to the  Traffic Inspector / Settings admin page. Add .aspx to the Request whitelist setting field.

Comment: An update: the better approach is to add `{.+\.aspx$}` See more: https://wpcerber.com/wordpress-probing-for-vulnerable-php-code/